# I don't know how to remove a strange symbol that appears in front of my equation

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In the third line of my equation, a strange Greek letter appears and I would like to remove it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
|E(h)-E(h+1)|&=\left|(kz*r+kz)\sin\left( \frac{Gz}{r+1}\right)+(-r^2-2*r-1)cos\left( \frac{Gz}{r+1}\right)\right.\\
&\hspace{1cm}+(ky*r+ky)sin\left( \frac{Gy}{r+1}\right)+(-r^2-2r-1)cos\left( \frac{Gy}{r+1}\right)\\
&+(kx*r+kx)sin\left( \frac{Gx}{r+1}\right)+(-r^2-2*r-1)cos\left( \frac{Gx}{r+1}\right)\\
&+(-cos\left( \frac{Gz}{r}\right)-cos\left( \frac{Gy}{r}\right)-cos\left( \frac{Gx}{r}\right)+6)*r^2\\
&\left.+(kz\sin\left( \frac{Gz}{r}\right)+ky*\sin\left( \frac{Gy}{r}\right)+kx\sin\left( \frac{Gz}{r}\right)+6)*r+3\right|
\end{aligned}•
\end{equation*}•    
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the strange symbol is... ?

You have in your MWE two bullets at the end of the `aligned` and `equation*` environments. That's the only strange I see. The ligature `ffl` could be also strange.

Comment: @Aradnix : I already erase the bullets, but i don´t know what is a "ligature ffl", even erasing the bullets the strange symbol like a greek letter still in my pdf.

Comment: I erased the bullets and now the ligature dissapeared. What editor are using you?

Comment: @Aradnix: Yes, I erased too and the symbol dissppeared. I'm with Texworks. How I vote for your answer?

Comment: I didn't see any strange symbol

Comment: @JuanMuñoz Now you'll see the answer. Check it out.

Comment: @skpblack: I have corrected the making appear again the strange symbol, the symbol appear for the two bullets at the end of the code, I erased accidentaly in my question, that is why you did't see the symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see any strange symbol either. Perhaps it is a problem with the encoding of your source file.

I suggest a slightly different alignment; with and without (smaller) parentheses around the fractions and a correct definition for absolute value, borrowed from an example in `mathtools` (it's needless to  load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert%

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\abs[\Big]{E(h)-E(h+1)} = & \left\lvert(kz*r+kz)\sin \frac{Gz}{r+1}+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos \frac{Gz}{r+1}\right.\\
 & +(ky*r+ky)\sin \frac{Gy}{r+1}+(-r^2-2r-1)\cos \frac{Gy}{r+1}\\
 & +(kx*r+kx)\sin \frac{Gx}{r+1}+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos \frac{Gx}{r+1}\\
 & +\Bigl(-\cos \frac{Gz}{r}-\cos \frac{Gy}{r}-\cos \frac{Gx}{r}+6\Bigr)*r^2\\
 & \left.+\Bigl(kz\sin \frac{Gz}{r}+ky*\sin \frac{Gy}{r}+kx\sin \frac{Gz}{r}+6\Bigr)*r+3\right\rvert
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\abs[\Big]{E(h)-E(h+1)} = & \left\lvert(kz*r+kz)\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gz}{r+1}\Bigr)+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gz}{r+1}\Bigr)\right.\\
 & +(ky*r+ky)\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gy}{r+1}\Bigr)+(-r^2-2r-1)\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gy}{r+1}\Bigr)\\
 & +(kx*r+kx)\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gx}{r+1}\Bigr)+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gx}{r+1}\Bigr)\\
 & +\Bigl(-\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gz}{r}\Bigr)-\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gy}{r}\Bigr)-\cos\Bigl( \frac{Gx}{r}\Bigr)+6\Bigr)*r^2\\
 & \left.+\Bigl(kz\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gz}{r}\Bigr)+ky*\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gy}{r}\Bigr)+kx\sin\Bigl( \frac{Gz}{r}\Bigr)+6\Bigr)*r+3\right\rvert
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, from your MWE I removed those strange bullets at the end of the code, since you're loading the `amsmath` package, we can improve the code with it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\bigl|E(h)-E(h+1)\bigr|&=\Biggl|(kz*r+kz)\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gz}{r+1}\biggr)+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gz}{r+1}\biggr)\\
        &\hspace{1cm}+(ky*r+ky)\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gy}{r+1}\biggr)+(-r^2-2r-1)\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gy}{r+1}\biggr)\\
        &+(kx*r+kx)\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gx}{r+1}\biggr)+(-r^2-2*r-1)\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gx}{r+1}\biggr)\\
        &+\Biggl[-\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gz}{r}\biggr)-\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gy}{r}\biggr)-\cos\biggl( \dfrac{Gx}{r}\biggr)+6\Biggr]*r^2\\
        &+(kz\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gz}{r}\biggr)+ky*\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gy}{r}\biggr)+kx\sin\biggl( \dfrac{Gz}{r}\biggr)+6)*r+3\Biggr|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```